# How to Conditionally Record Values from One Dataframe into Another?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

Here I read in a dataframe named BTC from a csv. It contains columns named High, Low, Open and Close. I then create a blank df for conditionally recording values from BTC

```
BTC = pd.read_csv(r'C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/uni/Processedbtcplevel.csv')

movement = pd.DataFrame(pd.np.empty((0, 4))) 
movement.columns =['High', 'Low', 'Open', 'Close']
```

I then have a function intended to check another column: 'TrendOrders'. The TrendOrders column is empty for rows between a 'buy' string and a 'stopped' string, but the rest of the row contains the values I want. I am trying to keep the values that begin at a "buy" and end at a "stopped" string.

```
def pricemovement(row):

    if row['TrendOrders']=='buy':
        record.loc[0, 'buyorder'] = 'True'        
    elif row['TrendOrders'] == 'Stopped':
        record.loc[0, 'buyorder'] = 'False'        
    if record.loc[0, 'buyorder'] =='True':
        High = row["High"]
        Low= row['Low']
        Close= row["Close"]
        Open= row["Open"]
        movement.append({'High':High}, ignore_index=True)
        movement.append({'Low':Low}, ignore_index=True)
        movement.append({'Close':Close}, ignore_index=True)
        movement.append({'Open':Open}, ignore_index=True)
    else:
        movement.append({'High':0}, ignore_index=True)
        movement.append({'Low':0}, ignore_index=True)
        movement.append({'Close':0}, ignore_index=True)
        movement.append({'Open':0}, ignore_index=True)   
        
BTC.apply(pricemovement, axis=1)

movement.to_csv(r'C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/movement.csv', index = False)
```

Instead, applying this function gives an empty dataframe. Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not provided sample data so I've simulated it.

It's far simpler to just define a new column (as you have tried) and then filter based on this.  No need for loops.  Have excluded calculated column as you do not copy it in your sample code.

You can do `movement.to_csv()` to output.

```
import numpy as np
BTC = pd.DataFrame({
    "High":np.random.choice(100,5),
    "Low":np.random.choice(100,5),
    "Open":np.random.choice(100,5),
    "Close":np.random.choice(100,5),
    "TrendOrders":np.random.choice(["buy","sell","hold"],5)})

BTC["BuyOrder"] = BTC["TrendOrders"].eq("buy")  # add columns as per question
movement = BTC[BTC["BuyOrder"]].loc[:,BTC.columns != "BuyOrder"] # filter results using mask
movement
```

### output

```
    High    Low Open    Close   TrendOrders
0   53  90  34  30  buy
1   98  54  16  48  buy
2   71  97  61  83  buy
4   33  80  50  72  buy
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't believe the original wording of my question has made my intentions clear enough (I've updated it for clarity). Your answer here returns the values only for rows where 'buy' was in the TrendOrders column. The TrendOrders column is empty for rows between a 'buy' string and a 'stopped' string, but the rest of the row contains the values I want. I am trying to keep the values that begin at a "buy" and end at a "stopped" string.